# disable cell when user click on 'add new' in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

My settings are as given below. 
when I click on the 'add new' link the ID cell is editable. We want to make that field uneditable.

```
mySettings = {
columns: {
        id: {
            title: 'ID',
            editable: false,
        },
        name: {
            title: 'Name',
        },
        lastname: {
            title: 'Last Name',
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue.
we need to add an attribute `addable: false` to the respected column. This attribute is not mentioned in ng2-smart-table doc.

```
tableSettings = {
    mode: 'inline',
      columns: {
        name: {
          title: 'Name',
          editable:false,
          addable: false,
        },
        lastname: {
          title: 'Last Name',
        },
      } // columns
  }
```

I found this solution in their example basic-example-load.
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/server/basic-example-load.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, it's so strange that they still don't have this in their documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use  `actions: false` in root object

```
tableSettings = {
      actions: false,
      columns: {
        lastname: {
          title: 'Last Name',
        },
      } // columns
  }
```